# Docker swarm - How to ensure service is linked correctly on update

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, docker-swarm, fpm, docker-stack

I'm using a compose file to deploy a stack on a swarm.
The stack contains (among others) nginx and php-fpm.

When updating the stack to newer image tags, using `docker stack deploy`, I get HTTP 502 errors while the php-fpm service is updating (it take a while as it builds some cache on startup).

What I experience today (or the way I suspect it works)

[image]

I would like a cleaner rolling update. What i expect is described here :

[image]

**How to achieve this ?**

Thanks for your appreciated help.

---

Error in nginx log when getting 502 :

`[error] 37#37: *104 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: viageo.ch, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://10.0.2.78:9000", host: "myservice.tld"`

---

v1 services docker-compose file (redacted) :

```yaml
version: '3.9'

x-deploy-base: &deployBase
    update_config:
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
    rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s

services:
    nginx:
        image: myregistry.local/myproject/nginx-deploy:v1
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "service", "nginx", "status" ]
        deploy:
            <<: *deployBase

    php-fpm:
        image: myregistry.local/myproject/php-fpm-deploy:v1
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        stop_grace_period: 10s
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "php-fpm-healthcheck" ]
        deploy:
            <<: *deployBase
    
    [other services...]
```

v2 services docker-compose file (redacted) :

```yaml
version: '3.9'

x-deploy-base: &deployBase
    update_config:
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
    rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s

services:
    nginx:
        image: myregistry.local/myproject/nginx-deploy:v2
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "service", "nginx", "status" ]
        deploy:
            <<: *deployBase

    php-fpm:
        image: myregistry.local/myproject/php-fpm-deploy:v2
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        stop_grace_period: 10s
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "php-fpm-healthcheck" ]
        deploy:
            <<: *deployBase
    
    [other services...]
```

Comment: Apologies for commenting on an old thread, but did you ever find a solution to this issue? We are experiencing the exact same problem and have tried multiple approaches to no avail (e.g. healthchecks, start-first update_config, different stop signals, stop_grace_period etc.). Thanks!

Comment: I seemed that my healthcheck was not working, using full path fixed it
`healthcheck:`
`test: [ "CMD", "/usr/local/bin/php-fpm-healthcheck" ]`